# Which socket must I import

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kalei\Desktop\bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.chrome()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.
```

Which socket must I import?

Answer (score 2):

Python is case-sensitive, so `chrome` should be `Chrome`, try `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` instead.